# Handle variables from multiple login for real-time chat

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io

I'm writing a nodejs server that combine a login function and real-time chat. The problem came when I try to get all the users that logged in and connected with my real-time chat server then return to the client (so they can choose a specific user to chat with).

This is my code for log in function. I declared a variable so when client request the /doLogin, the username will be stored in it

```
var userLogged = {name: null, socketid: null};

app.post('/doLogin', function(req,res){
    db.users.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, user) {
        if( err ) {
            console.log("Login fail");
        }
        else if (user != null) {
            if (req.body.password == user.password) {
                req.session.user_role = "user";
                userLogged.name = req.body.username;
            } else {
                req.session.user_role = "null";
            }
        }
        res.send({redirect: "/"});
    });

});
```

And in real-time chat function (using Socket.io), when user connect (after logged in), I will store the socket.id into the variable before, and save that variable in mongodb.

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
     var address = socket.handshake.address;
     userLogged.socketid = socket.id;

     db.clientList.save({name: userLogged.name, socketid: userLogged.socketid}, function(err, saved){
     });
    console.log("Connection " + address.address + " accepted.");
    //
    //
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        db.clientList.remove({socketid: userLogged.socketid});
    });
});
```

And the problem is, when other users log in, the variable change so I cannot save the right information in to database.
Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

socket.io allow you to read cookies:

```
// app.js
io = io.listen(server);
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
    handshakeData.cookie = cookie.parse(handshakeData.headers.cookie);
});
```

the right way to do is:

```
cookies --> sessionID --> user --> username
```

document: http://howtonode.org/socket-io-auth

---

More simple:

if security is not important to you, you can set username to cookie, then you read username in easily in server: `cookies->username`

```
// login handler
res.cookie('username', username)
res.send({redirect: "/"});

// io connection handler
io = io.listen(server);
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
    console.log(handshakeData.headers.cookie)
}
```

note that, any web user can change their own cookie to fake your name, so this is for test, you should NOT use this for production.